# WPF TreeView binding to a simple object

Tags: wpf, treeview, binding

I have a simple object as such:

```
public class Info
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Count {get; set;}
    public DateTime TimeStamp {get; set;}
}
```

I want to bind a collection of these objects to a WPF TreeView and have the properties on the Info objects show up as sub TreeViewItems, like so:

- Item 1

  - Name: Bill
  - Count: 3
  - TimeStamp: 12/05/2010 09:06:00 AM
- Item 2

  - Name: Chris
  - Count: 22
  - TimeStamp: 11/05/2010 11:34:00 AM
- Item 3

  - Name: Toby
  - Count: 1
  - TimeStamp: 09/05/2010 05:55:00 PM

How can I achieve this through XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a InfoViewModel which has

```
  (Prop)  Item Index : 1
  (Prop)  Children   : ["Bill", 3, timestampvalue]
```

Map your list of Info objects to a list of InfoViewModels.

DataBind your tree to this list ; use DataContext and ItemsSource to point to your List

Define a HierarchicalDataTemplate for InfoViewModel and bind the ItemsSource property to InfoViewModel.Children. 
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912481) for similar code sample.

Comment: Either this doesn't work for me, or the description is too superficial to be helpful, I'm afraid :-/