# XML databinding to TreeView with child nodes of different types under the same parent

Tags: wpf, xml, data-binding, treeview

**Note: See the bottom of this post for the solution.**

I'm trying to use XAML's "HierarchicalDataTemplate" to display an xml document in a TreeView.
My current XAML code will display the first child of the "Parent" node but not subsequent child nodes of different types.

**Can I use XAML to display children of different types under a common parent?**

I've boiled the problem down to a very basic sample for illustrative purposes.

I want my treeview to look like this (minus the stuff in parenthesis):

```
Parent: Roger (Type="Parent")
 |--Rug rats (Type="Children")
 |     |--Bob (Type="Child")
 |     |--Tom
 |
 |--Gear (Type="Equipment")  <-- **can't display this or its child nodes**
       |--Canoe (Type="Item")
       |--Tent
```

In this example, "Parent" nodes have 2 types of child nodes; "Children" and "Equipment".

Here's the XML:

```
<Parent Name="Roger">
   <Children>
     <Child Name="Bob"/>
     <Child Name="Tom"/>
  </Children>
  <EquipmentList>
     <Item Name="Canoe"/>
     <Item Name="Tent"/>
   </EquipmentList>
</Parent>
```

Here's the XAML data templates to render the tree nodes:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Parent" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Children}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text=": "/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Children" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Child}">
        <TextBox Width="Auto" Text="Rug Rats" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Child">
        <TextBox Width="Auto" Text="{Binding XPath=@Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="EquipmentList" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Item}">
        <TextBox Width="Auto" Text="Gear" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Item">
        <TextBox Width="Auto" Text="{Binding XPath=@Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
```

In the interest of completeness, here is the code behind that fills the tree:

```
_xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
_xmlDoc.Load(@"..\..\SampleXMLFile.xml");

treeViewToolDescription.ItemsSource = _xmlDoc;
```

I've been Googling combinations of "XML", "TreeView", "HierarchicalDataTemplate" and "heterogeneous" for a couple of days so I've seen (yet obviously not understood) quite a few articles that *looked* promising but never seemed relevant enough.

**SOLUTION**

The solution was to use an asterisk for the ItemsSource to get all the children regardless of type i.e. ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}"

**Before** (ItemsSource set explicitly to type "Children"):

```
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Parent" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Children}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Parent: "/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

**After** (ItemsSource set to "*" instead of specifying a type):

```
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Parent" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=*}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Parent: "/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you can't as it stands. You'll need to create one property which collates all children of a given node as one property.

So in this case you need a SubNodes property like the following

```
Parent.SubNodes => a list {Rug Rats, Gear}
Children.SubNodes for Rug Rats=> a list {Bob, Tom} 
Equipment.SubNodes for Gear => a list {Canoe, Tent} Items
```

and you can use DataTemplates for each type to render how each leaf node looks. A similar question [WPF TreeView HierarchicalDataTemplate - binding to object with multiple child collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912481)