# Display hierarchy in wpf with unlimited number of levels

Tags: c#, wpf, hierarchy

I have a collection of contacts stored as a hierarchy with an unlimited number of levels.  To be more specific, each `ContactItem` has a `List<ContactItem>`.  I have a couple reasons why:

1) Groups of contacts are also `ContactItems` to allow more flexibility.

2) A family, company, etc may have a phone number, and then each individual has a phone number.

Examples would be "School -> Teachers -> Mr. Perry" or "Smith -> Bob, Elen"

Anyway, I'm wondering if there's an easy way to display such a hierarchy with an unlimited number of levels easily in WPF.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to search for HierarchicalDataTemplate  here are some samples

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36451/Organizing-Heterogeneous-Data-on-a-WPF-TreeView

[WPF TreeView HierarchicalDataTemplate - binding to object with multiple child collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912481/wpf-treeview-hierarchicaldatatemplate-binding-to-object-with-multiple-child-co)

http://complexdatatemplates.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out this control here: http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/01/wpf-treeview.

I think it may serve your needs.

Comment: It might take a while to figure out how to work it.  Not that I have any problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you stop adding new  objects and start pointing to them instead

```
public class Contact
{
   public static List<Contact> Library = new List<Contact>();

   public List<Contact> Contacts = new List<Contact>();
   protected string Name;

   public contact ( string Name )
   {
      this.Name = Name;
      Library.Add ( this );
   }

}
```

Then

```
Contact Ahmed = new Contact("Ahmed");
Contact Ghoneim = new Contact("Ghoneim");

Ahmed . Contacts . Add ( Contact . Library . First ( C => C . Name == "Ghoneim" ) );
```