# Bind WPF Tree to a one to many object using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a categories class which has subcategories and a subcategory might have subcategory and so on. I want to create a data binding for a hierarchical tree with click command for each node.

This is my class.

```
public partial class ProductCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    #region Foreign Keys
    public ProductCategory ParentProductCategory { get; set; }
    public int? ParentProductCategoryId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductCategory> ChildProductCategories { get; set; }
    #endregion
    public virtual ICollection<ProductType> ProductTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg how do i create the binding i found similar topics but they talk about deterministic number and type of child objects.

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg here as you can the relation is one to many, parent object is the same type as the child, so there might be a need for some recursion.

Comment: @MozartAlkhateeb Read about `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. It is what you are looking for.

Comment: Whats the problem using solutions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912481/wpf-treeview-hierarchicaldatatemplate-binding-to-object-with-multiple-child-co ?

Comment: @Karolis  i'll check both suggestions.

Comment: Create `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for both, `ProductCategory` and `ProductType`, in View model create collection of `ProductCategory` and bind this list as tree source.

Comment: @sTrenat actually i don't care about the ProductType in this page. can you please elaborate a bit more, this is the first time i work with HierarchicalDataTemplate

Comment: Create list to bind in your VM, e.g ObservableCollection<ProductCategory> with your first layer data, bind to it. Then in your TreeView.Resources, add HierarchicalDataTemplate, when targetType is ProductType, and bind it to `ProductTypes` proprety. That's all

Comment: Oh, you want just ProductCategory, my mistake :d I'm not sure if you can do treeView with just one property inside, isntead of list. But you could always make, instead of ParentProductCategory, list of subcategories. then, same as i wrote in upper comment.
Damn, i'm blind xD You already have childs, so it's like i said in first comment :d

Comment: @sTrenat yes i want to display child categories, the child-child-categories and so on, i'll try that out anw.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved my problem...

**Code Behind (View Model)**

```
public class ProductCategoryViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<ProductCategory> _productCategories;

    public ObservableCollection<ProductCategory> ProductCategories
    {
        get => _productCategories;
        set => Set(ref _productCategories, value);
    }
    public RelayCommand<string> ClickCategoryCommand { get; set; }

    public ProductCategoryViewModel()
    {
        _productCategories = new ObservableCollection<ProductCategory>();
        var p1 = new ProductCategory()
        {
            Description = "P1",
            ChildProductCategories = new List<ProductCategory>()
            {
                new ProductCategory()
                {
                    Description = "C1",
                    ChildProductCategories = new List<ProductCategory>()
                    {
                        new ProductCategory()
                        {
                            Description = "C1 C1"
                        },
                        new ProductCategory()
                        {
                            Description = "C1 C2"
                        }
                    }
                },
                new ProductCategory()
                {
                    Description = "C2"
                }
            }
        };
        _productCategories.Add(p1);
        ClickCategoryCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(Click);
    }

    private void Click(string description)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(description);
    }
}
```

**Xaml Code**

```
  <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ProductCategories}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ProductCategory}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildProductCategories}">
                <Button Content="{Binding Path=Description}" 
                           Command="{Binding DataContext.ClickCategoryCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding Description}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```