# WPF TreeView - what element type should my ObservableCollection be to bind it to its DataSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

MVVM style. Wihtout messing with the view too much, preferably - without touching the view.

Is it possible to create a collection that will just contain the nested items and the `TreeView` would just display them?

I've seen an example with a `MenuItem` used as the data type. What if I don't want to use `MenuItem`? I assume, my item should just implement an interface that defines how it can contain other items. What is this interface?

Also - I need to have a checkbox on each item, but that's probably a matter of providing the item template.

Then again, a `MenuItem` can be checked, that might be useful ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF TreeView HierarchicalDataTemplate - binding to object with multiple child collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912481/wpf-treeview-hierarchicaldatatemplate-binding-to-object-with-multiple-child-co)

Comment: Yes, it's a special case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beauty of the ItemsControl classes in WPF (including ListBox and TreeView) is that the items source can be a collection of any type you like. There's no reason why it has has to be a UI based class - in fact with templates, it probably should never should be.

You then set the ItemTemplate to define what UI is displayed for each item in the ItemsSource collection.

e.g.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public List<Person> Children {get;} = new List<Person>();
}


public class MainViewModel
{
    public List<Person> PersonList {get;} = new List<Person>();
} 



<TreeView
    ItemsSource = {Binding PersonList} >
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate
            ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <StackPanel>
                <Textblock Text={Binding FirstName} />
                <Textblock Text={Binding LastNameName} />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Take a look at my [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-behaviors-part-2-treeview/) for a deeper discussion on how to handle TreeView controls in a MVVM context.

Comment: YES! This is beautiful! I coded my tree in 5 minutes done and done, worked at first attempt ;) I read the post, more details there, but I'm glad you just showed the basic example, so I practically finished my UI in no time. I usually don't do front-ends, so each time I need one I'm a little rusty and confused ;)