How do I create a treeView for a List<List<int>?
I have a EntityDisplay class that contains 2 properties:
public sealed class EntityDisplayObject
{

    public ICollection Collection { get; private set; }

    public string CollectionName { get; private set; }

    public EntityDisplayObject(ICollection collection)
    {
        this.Collection = collection;

        this.CollectionName = $"{this.Collection.GetType().Name [{this.Collection.Count}]";
    }

}
Sometimes Collection will be a List<int>, but sometimes it will be a List<List<int>.
I currently have it working for List, but can not find a way to do it for nested lists.
This is my xaml at the moment:
<Grid x:Uid="Grid_4">

    <TreeView x:Uid="TreeView_2"
              Background="Transparent"
              BorderThickness="0"
              Padding="0">

        <TreeViewItem x:Uid="TreeViewItem_1"
                      Header="{Binding CollectionName}">

            <ListBox x:Uid="ListBox_2" MouseDoubleClick="TreeViewItem_MouseDoubleClick"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
                     Background="Transparent"
                     BorderThickness="0">
            </ListBox>

        </TreeViewItem>

    </TreeView>
</Grid>

Simple list working with the xaml
For nested lists, I get the tree view header and expandable option, but instead of showing me the list as the first screenshot, it gives me (Collection).
Nested list currently

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78556341/3392605

Focus on the structure of Class_ParentChild_Model, you will get it, or post your class code for simple List<string>

so.. you want a hierachial treeview? eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912481

@RandRandom thank you that helped! At the end what I had to was extract all the items inside the collection and add it to a new List (that is done inside some if checks to make sure that Collection has items inside, then if any of those items is a collection as well, it will repeat the process. Finally, in the xaml inside a tree view I bind an itemsControl to this new List.

Thanks everyone for the help. At the end, this code did the job. What I had to do is for each collection, get the items and put them inside a new List property, and if any of the items are also collections, do the same to them which will give each object a List of children (if they are a collection).
foreach (var child in collection)
{
    if (child is ICollection childCollection && childCollection.Count > 0)
{
    var childObject = new EntityDisplayObject(childCollection);
    this.ChildCollection.Add(childObject);
}

And this is how the xaml looks like to be able to display something like this
Item 1
  -Item 2
    -Item 3
    -Item 4
    -Item 5
      -Item 6
  -Item 7

<TreeView x:Uid="TreeView_2"
          Background="Transparent"
          BorderThickness="0"
          Padding="0"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

    <TreeViewItem x:Uid="TreeViewItem_1"
                  Header="{Binding CollectionName}">

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ChildCollection}"
                      ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource EntityInspectorDataTemplateSelector}"
                      Background="Transparent"
                      BorderThickness="0">
            
        </ItemsControl>

    </TreeViewItem>

</TreeView>


If you don't want to convert your data structure you can define a DataTemplateSelector that detects the actual type of the EntityDisplayObject.Collection items and selects the appropriate DataTemplate:
class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
  public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }
  public DataTemplate NestedListTemplate { get; set; }

  public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container) 
    => item is IEnumerable 
      ? this.NestedListTemplate 
      : this.DefaultTemplate;
}

<Window xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:collections="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=System.Runtime">
  <TreeView x:Uid="TreeView_2"
            Background="Transparent"
            BorderThickness="0"
            Padding="0">

    <TreeViewItem x:Uid="TreeViewItem_1"
                  Header="{Binding CollectionName}">

      <ListBox x:Uid="ListBox_2"
               ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
               Background="Transparent"
               BorderThickness="0">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
          <local:MyDataTemplateSelector>
            <local:MyDataTemplateSelector.DefaultTemplate>
              <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:Int32}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
              </DataTemplate>
            </local:MyDataTemplateSelector.DefaultTemplate>

            <local:MyDataTemplateSelector.NestedListTemplate>
              <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type collections:IList}">
                <HeaderedItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
              </DataTemplate>
            </local:MyDataTemplateSelector.NestedListTemplate>
          </local:MyDataTemplateSelector>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
      </ListBox>
    </TreeViewItem>
  </TreeView>
</Window>


However, a nested list is a bad choice to implement a tree data structure in OO programming. It will introduce some oddities.
I recommend converting your data structure as this will make working with your data and views much simpler. So instead of a List<List<int>> you can use a List<EntityDisplayObject>. For performance reasons the example replaces List<T> with ObservableCollection<T>:
EntityDisplayObject.cs
class EntityDisplayObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ObservableCOllection<EntityDisplayObject> Children { get; }

  public object Value { get; }

  public EntityDisplay(object value) : this(Enumerable.Empty<EntityDisplayObject>(), value)
  {
  }

  public EntityDisplay(IEnumerable<EntityDisplayObject> children, object value)
  {
    this.Children = new ObservableCollection<EntityDisplayObject>(children);
    this.Value = value;
  }
}

MainWindow.xaml.cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public ObservableCollection<EntityDisplayObject> TreeData { get; } 

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
    this.TreeData = new ObservableCollection<EntityDisplayObject>();
  }

  private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {    
    var rootItem = new EntityDisplayObject("Root");

    // Create a child without nested children. 
    // Children are a simple list of int values.
    var intChildren = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
    var simpleChild = new EntityDisplayObject(intChildren, "Simple child");
    rootItem.Children.Add(simpleChild);

    // Create a child with nested children.
    // Each child contains a list of int values
    IEnumerable<EntityDisplayObject> nestedChildren = Enumerable
      .Range(11, 10)
      .Select(value => 
        {
          var children = Enumerable.Range(100 * value, 10)
            .Select(childValue => new EntityDisplayObject(childValue));
          var child = new EntityDisplayObject(children, value);
        });
    var nestedChildrenParent = new EntityDisplayObject(nestedChildren, "Nested child #1");
    rootItem.Add(nestedChildrenParent);
  
    // Create another child with nested children.
    // Each child contains a list of int values
    nestedChildren = Enumerable
      .Range(21, 10)
      .Select(value => 
        {
          var children = Enumerable.Range(200 * value, 10)
            .Select(childValue => new EntityDisplayObject(childValue));
          var child = new EntityDisplayObject(children, value);
        });
    nestedChildrenParent = new EntityDisplayObject(nestedChildren, "Nested child #1");
    rootItem.Add(nestedChildrenParent);

    this.TreeData.Add(rootItem);
  }
}

MainWindow.xaml
<Window x:Name="VisualRoot">
  <TreeView ItemsSource={Binding ElementName=VisualRoot, Path=TreeData}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type EntityDisplayObject}" 
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
  </TreeView>
</Window>


Shouldn't this.Children = children; be this.Children = new(children);?

For performance reasons the example replaces List<T> with ObservableCollection<T>: - do you have some documentation stating that performance issue?

@KostasK. Yes, exactly. I wrote this code here in the text editor without type checking. Obviously, I was a little bit sloppy. Thanks for pointing that out.

@RandRandom There isn't a single Microsoft article. It's my knowledge based on several Microsoft articles and source code reviews. Please read: Binding to list causes memory leak for a brief summary. Another point that is not mentioned in that post is that using an INotifyCollectionChanged implementation allows to update the source collection instance instead of replacing it to update the view, which avoids a complete render pass of the ItemsControl. which can be really expensive (it usually causes the UI to freeze).
